# Html filter form. Javascript doesn't allow more then one field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a category filter. It works, however I´m trying to add another form field with
radio buttons for multiple selections. However, only 1 button can be selected. If I click a radiobutton from the first formfield that button works, but if I click on a radiobutton on another form filed it will select that one instead, I need to be able to choose both. The checkbox input type works though.

Fiddle here: [Fiddle](http://cssdeck.com/labs/aqijb5kx)

The HTML:

```
<style>.body .item .textnoimgleftlarge {width: auto;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
<div class="filterGenius">
<form name="PC">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h3>Desktop filter</h3><br></td>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2"><a class="filterGeniusButton" onclick="removeFSS()">Clear all filters</a></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60px"><b>CPU</b></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="processor" value="C2D"/><span>C2D</span></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="processor" value="DC-"/><span>Dualcore</span></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="processor" value="i3-"/><span>i3</span></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="processor" value="i5-"/><span>i5</span></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="processor" value="i7-"/><span>i7</span></label></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="60px"><b>Specifications</b></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="SSD"/><span>SSD</input></span></label>            </td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="WLAN"/><span>WLAN</input></span> </label></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="W7P"/><span>W7P</input></span></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="W8P"/><span>W8P</input></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="SFF"/><span>SFF</input></span></label>   </td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="processor" value="AIO"/><span>All in one</input></span>   </label></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```js
<script>
function removeFSS(){ga("send","event","button","click","filter-clear");var e=$.query.get("fss");encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%20/g,"+");$(".filterGenius input").each(function(){var t=this;t="\\ "+$(t).val();var n=new RegExp(t,"g");e=e.replace(n,"")});var t=encodeURI(unescape($.query.set("fss",e)));var n=window.location.href.split("?")[0];window.location.href=n+t}$(document).ready(function(){$(".filterGenius input").each(function(){if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val())>=0){$(this).attr("checked","checked")}});$(".filterGenius input").change(function(){if($(this).is(":checked")){ga("send","event","button","click","filter-on");var e=$.query.get("fss");if(e==true){e=""}encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%20/g,"+");var t=$(this).val();var n="%2B"+t;var r=new RegExp(n,"g");e.replace(r,"");var i=e;if($(this).is(":radio")){$(".filterGenius input[type=radio]").each(function(){var e=this;e="\\ "+$(e).val();var t=new RegExp(e,"g");i=i.replace(t,"")})}var i=i+"+"+t;var s=encodeURI(unescape($.query.set("fss",i)));$(".filterGenius input").attr("disabled",true);var o=window.location.href.split("?")[0];window.location.href=o+s}else if(!$(this).is(":checked")){ga("send","event","button","click","filter-off");var e=$.query.get("fss").toString();if(e===undefined){}else if(e=="true"){e=""}else{encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%20/g,"+");var t=$(this).val();var n="\\ "+t;var r=new RegExp(n,"g");e=e.replace(r,"");if($(this).is(":radio")){$(".filterGenius input[type=radio]").each(function(){var t=$(this).val();var n="\\ "+t;console.log(e);console.log(n);var r=new RegExp(n,"g");e.replace(r,"");console.log("FSS RADIO: "+e)})}var i=e;var s=encodeURI(unescape($.query.set("fss",i)));$(".filterGenius input").attr("disabled",true);var o=window.location.href.split("?")[0];window.location.href=o+s}}})})
</script>
```

Comment: Ensure both radio groups have different names. In your src I don't see two radio groups though?

Comment: Oh thats right, i removed it. Question was more how I do add another group.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not the problem. What you describe is expected behavior of radio buttons and checkboxes. Radio buttons allow only one item to be selected at a time. Here's a nice article on which control is [appropriate](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/). To make radio buttons independent you have to use different **name** attribute.

Comment: You mean the name"processor"? Tried to change the name but still wont work. will take a look at the link, thanks.

Comment: And Ill do understand that the radiobutton only can be selcted once.. But shouldnt it be possible to be able to choose two radiobuttons in the same time in different groups? Or can I have a group of checkboxes and make it so I can only click per group?

Comment: *name* attribute is how you define [groups](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

Comment: I understand the group naming. But when I have two different groups i can still only choose on radiobutton from those groups. If i choose a button in group 1 it works. If I then choose a radiobutton in group 2, it removes the first button i clicked. I want to be able to click on a button in each group at the same time

Comment: You're probably confusing something, because if you define groups correctly that wouldn't happen. Name half of radio buttons that are "processor" something different, say "processor1". And try to select one of each.